# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in PHP 5.5.9

Tags: php, parse-error

I've the following code:

```
<?php if ($template['issue']['raw_state'] == 0 && ($helper->user_coordinator($template['issue']['id']) || isset($nparams['tid']))): ?>
    <a href="?id=<?php echo $this->id('cause_form', 'id', $template['issue']['id']) ?>">
        <?php echo $bezlang['add_cause'] ?>
    </a>
<? endif ?>
```

It works well on most of my servers but on one of them I receive an error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in
>   /var/www/dokuwiki/lib/plugins/bez/tpl/issue_causes.php on line 19,

What is wrong with this code?

The entire file issue_cause.php:

```
<?php include "issue_box.php" ?>

<div class="bds_block" id="bez_causes">
    <h1><?php echo $bezlang['causes'] ?> <span>(<?php echo count($template['causes']) ?>)</span></h1>
    <div class="bds_block_content">
        <?php foreach ($template['causes'] as $cause): ?>
            <?php include "cause.php" ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
    <?php if ($template['issue']['raw_state'] == 0 && ($helper->user_coordinator($template['issue']['id']) || isset($nparams['tid']))): ?>
        <a href="?id=<?php echo $this->id('cause_form', 'id', $template['issue']['id']) ?>">
            <?php echo $bezlang['add_cause'] ?>
        </a>
    <? endif ?>
</div>

<?php include "removal_confirm.php" ?>
```

Comment: `on line 19`, but you show only 17 lines here. Are you sure you show us the correct and real file here?

Comment: you need a semicolon after endofreach and  endif like like `<?php endforeach; ?>` and `<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: He has not used any where `;`.

Comment: Make sure short tags are enabled on all servers.

Comment: more of a "why isn't my code working" question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Could you replace <? endif ?> with <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: You're right. How can I overlook that? Old shot_tag_open problem.